# controlling vlc from c# using http requests with credentials

Tags: c#, vlc

I want to add a button to my form that sends "play" command to vlc player in the same network.
i'm using this code to send http request:

```
private void VlcPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String URI = "http://192.168.1.5:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_play";
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
    stream.Close();
}
```

the problem is that vlc requests: username=blank + password="1234" (can be changed).
- vlc doesn't allow setting a username, it must be empty. (stupid)
- vlc does't allow connecting without 'some' password.

i've tried doing this:

```
private void VlcPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String URI = "http://192.168.1.5:8080/requests/status.xml?command=pl_play";

    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" + ":" + "1234"));
    webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);
    Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
    stream.Close();
}
```

Doesn't work.

How do i send password only without username?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found a solution myself after trying like 100 things :)

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(null + ":" + "1234"));
```

Comment: or (in a shorter form): `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(":1234")`... or `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("" + ":" + "1234")`, which is exactly the same as your original example. Are you sure this was the fix?